# Write a custom filter with ransack using arel_predicates and regular expressions (RoR 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have a model called 'employee' which i'm using the gem 'ancestry' on.

Basically what this gem does is it 'stores' all the `ancestors_ids` (parents) data of this employee in a string column called `'ancestry'` that looks like this `"1/2/3"`. So if an employee's ancestry looked like `"1/2/3"`, that would mean that his ancestors are employee's whose id's are `3`(parent), `2`(parent of `3`), and `1`(parent of `2`).

I have a custom filter written with ransack that looks like this:

```
  ransacker :managers_ids, type: :integer do
    Arel.sql("replace(employees.ancestry, '/', ' ')")
  end
```

and i have a custom search method that uses arel_predicates that looks like this:

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'special_in',
    arel_predicate: 'matches_regexp',
    # Converts string array into array and join with | that are OR in regex SQL
    formatter: proc { |v| "#{JSON.parse(v).join("|")}"},
    type: :array
end
```

When I apply this filter with ransack, like this: `q[managers_ids_special_in][]=1 2 3`, what it does is it replaces all the dashes `/` in the column with spaces, leaving a string that looks like "1 2 3" and then the `special_in` predicate uses `'matches_regexp'` to find values in the ancestry column that match those i sent in the array.

This "works". The problem is that if my ancestry column looked like `"11/22/33/1/2/3"` and i used `q[managers_ids_special_in][]=1 2 3`, this would match all the values, since `'special_in'` matches '1' with '11', '2' with '22', and '3' with '33'.

I want to avoid this, I've been trying out different predicates, or a way to "change" my current solution to achieve this but it's a bit over my comprehension. I was hoping any of you more experienced with ransack and arel could help me out here. Maybe point me in the right direction, or explain to me why this way does not work, so i can get to a solution.

These are the arel predicates i was trying to use to achieve my goal:

> https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/208fe3690d840d0ee65b1395a891886e58fd3f4b/lib/arel/predications.rb#L126

And i also found thise:

> https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/constants.rb

But as i said, i see a lot of information and don't really know how to use it (been on rails for around 7 months now)

Thanks in advance for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I would consider spliting the string into an array and using the array operators instead of a regex. For example on PG you could do `?  = ANY(string_to_array(employees.ancestry, '/'))`.

Comment: Hey @max, thank you for your input. I had fiddled around with 'string_to_array' before, but couldn't get a proper solution working, i know your answer it's really close to the solution i need, but i'm not quite there yet.Do you think you could take a look at the SQL query as of now? Maybe that'll clear things up.  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "employees"."id") FROM "employees" WHERE ?  = ANY(string_to_array(employees.ancestry, '/')) ~ '1|2'` (i removed the unimportant parts from the query, something that had to do with 'employees.type')

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Comment: @max Yes i am using Postgres. Sorry about the late reply i couldn't get to a computer any sooner.

Comment: @max Do you think i might be missing a nested select to proprely apply string_to_array? Something like -> `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "employees" . "id" FROM "employees" WHERE (SELECT string_to_array('employees.ancestry') FROM "employees"  ~ '1|2' ) ) )` (i 'm not very good writing queries, as you can see, but i have an idea of what i need) i'm trying queries here: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html since i don't have my computer on me